# npm - set project specific default prefix/path

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like `npm ...` to always run in the context of a subfolder of my project: "./assets".

When I run this command from the project root, it behaves as expected:

```
$ npm --prefix ./assets install
```

However, it does not read this from the `.npmrc` in the root folder.

```
$ echo "prefix=./assets" > .npmrc
$ npm i
# creates an empty ./node_modules folder
```

How can I set a set project specific default prefix for npm commands?

Comment: I see that there was an open issue on this apparent bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8036. However, it was closed with a comment related to global installation (npm i -g). I'm not sure that addressed the issue. If you run 'npm config get prefix', it shows the prefix value defined in ${PROJECT}/.npmrc. But, 'npm i' still installs to node_modules. But passing --prefix does install to the specified subdirectory.

Comment: Still not fixed with NPM 5.0.3

Answer (score -1):

If you have install npm globally you can simply configure prefix to set for specific folder so that you can install other node modules to that folder. Following is the command to set prefix.

npm config set prefix /Programming/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/

here i have configure Node in node-v0.10.31-linux-x64 this folder and node modules will be install there.

or

if you want to install node modules for specific folder individually you can user following command

npm install bower -g --prefix /Programming/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/

Comment: Thanks @Osanda, but I'm looking for a way to not have to specify the prefix for a given root folder. That is, in your example, I want to be able to install bower without `--prefix` and know that it will always install in the correct relative folder (e.g. `./assets`)